# Is there some kind of way to make sub-menu items?

Tags: java, user-interface, jmenu, jmenuitem, jmenubar

Say I had a JMenuBar. On that JMenuBar, I had a JMenu. On that JMenu, there was another menu, and on that menu, there were items. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! JMenu's can actually add other JMenu's... Why haven't I thought of that?